# awk : how to use variable value

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I want to declare a variable called `variableToUse` which holds the file name path.
I want to append file name with today's date.
Below code is in `myAWK.awk`

```
$bash: cat myAWK.awk
    BEGIN{
    today="date +%Y%m%d";
    variableToUse=/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_today.xml
    }

    /<record / { i=1 }
    i { a[i++]=$0 }
    /<\/record>/ {
        if (found) {
             print a[i] >> variableToUse
        }
    }
```

I am getting syntax error at `OutputFile_today.xml`.

How to use variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should quote the variables properly

**Example**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{variableToUse="/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_today.xml"; print variableToUse}'
/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_today.xml
```

- To get the current date you can use [`strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

**Example**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{today="date +%Y%m%d";variableToUse="/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_"strftime("%Y%m%d")".xml"; print variableToUse}'
/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_20160205.xml
```

Comment: The above code prints `/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_today.xml`. But I want, `/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_20160205.xml`

Comment: @user2488578 Sorry for that, I just noticed the error while creating the variable. updated the answer to get the `today` as required using `strftime`

Answer (score 1):

Have your awk script like this:

```
BEGIN {
   today="date +%Y%m%d";
   variableToUse="/MainDir/MainDir1/MainDir2/OutputFile_" today ".xml"
}

/<record / { i=1 }
i { a[i++]=$0 }
/<\/record>/ {
    if (found) {
         print a[i] >> variableToUse
    }
}
```

btw there are couple of other issues:
- I don't see `found` getting set anywhere in this script.
- `today="date +%Y%m%d"` will not execute `date command. It just assigns literal`date +%Y%m%d`to`today`variable. If you want to execute`date` command then use:

```
awk -v today="$(date '+%Y%m%d')" -f myAWK.awk
```

and remove `today=` line from `BEGIN` block.